# my android application is unfortunately getting stopped in eclipse but the same code of others is running good

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, logcat

This is the only activity which is not running  and its making application unfortunately stopped 
      (I am a beginner to the android  and actually i'm following the THENEWBOSTON'S android series old one (and his code is running well but as I tried it out, i didn't work )

```
public class Email extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    public static final String TAG = "my_Email";

    EditText personEmail, intro, personName, stupidThings, hatefulAction,
            outro;
    String emailAdd, begining, name, stupidAction, hateful, out;

    Button sendEmail;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.email);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate method invoked sucessful");

        personEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        intro = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        personEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        stupidThings = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        hatefulAction = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        outro = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
        sendEmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        sendEmail.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        Log.d(TAG, "onClick method invoked sucessful");


        String emailAddress[] = { emailAdd };

        Log.d(TAG, "String Array invoked sucessful");

        emailAdd = personEmail.getText().toString();
        begining = intro.getText().toString();
        name = personName.getText().toString();
        stupidAction = stupidThings.getText().toString();
        hateful = hatefulAction.getText().toString();
        out = outro.getText().toString();




        String message = "Assalamualaikum bhai "

        + name + begining + stupidAction + hateful + out;


        Log.d(TAG, "message created invoked sucessful");

        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        Log.d(TAG, "ACTION SEND added to intent sucessful");

        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,emailAddress );

        Log.d(TAG, "EMAIL ADDRESS added to intent sucessful");

        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"ALHAMDULILLAH SUCCESSFUL");

        Log.d(TAG, "SUBJECT added to intent sucessful");

        emailIntent.setType("plain/text");


        Log.d(TAG, "TEXT type added to intent sucessful");



        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);


        Log.d(TAG, "EXTRA TEXT added to intent sucessful");

        startActivity(emailIntent);


        Log.d(TAG, " intent called  sucessful");
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }

}
```

XML-File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="100" >

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="45" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="1dp"
                        android:text="Email Address(es)" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editText1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:paddingTop="1dp" >

                        <requestFocus
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                    </EditText>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="1dp"
                        android:text="Information" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editText2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:paddingTop="1dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="1dp"
                        android:text="Person&apos;s Name" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editText3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:paddingTop="1dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="1dp"
                        android:text="Studpid Things" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editText4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:paddingTop="1dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv5"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="1dp"
                        android:text="What you want to do with this person" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editText5"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:paddingTop="1dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv6"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="1dp"
                        android:text="Your message" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editText6"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:paddingTop="1dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                    </TextView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="15"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Send Email" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="40"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <AnalogClock
                    android:id="@+id/analogClock1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

LOGCAT logfile

```
      10-21 23:57:28.151: I/SELinux(4435): Function:      `enter code here`selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file.
10-21 23:57:28.151: I/SELinux(4435):  
10-21 23:57:28.211: I/SELinux(4435): Function: selinux_android_load_priority , spota verifySig and checkHash pass. priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-N9005_4.4.2_0046
10-21 23:57:28.211: I/SELinux(4435):  
10-21 23:57:28.211: I/SELinux(4435):  
10-21 23:57:28.211: I/SELinux(4435): selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /data/security/spota/seapp_contexts
10-21 23:57:28.211: E/dalvikvm(4435): >>>>> Normal User
10-21 23:57:28.211: E/dalvikvm(4435): >>>>> com.example.first [ userId:0 | appId:10296 ]
10-21 23:57:28.211: D/dalvikvm(4435): Late-enabling CheckJNI
10-21 23:57:28.601: W/ApplicationPackageManager(4435): getCSCPackageItemText()
10-21 23:57:28.601: I/PersonaManager(4435): getPersonaService() name persona_policy
10-21 23:57:28.641: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(4435): Parent view is not a TextView
10-21 23:57:28.761: D/dalvikvm(4435): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 97K, 37% free 17033K/26708K, paused 26ms, total 27ms
10-21 23:57:28.781: I/dalvikvm-heap(4435): Grow heap (frag case) to 32.307MB for 12582928-byte allocation
10-21 23:57:28.971: D/TextLayoutCache(4435): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-21 23:57:28.981: I/Adreno-EGL(4435): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
10-21 23:57:28.981: I/Adreno-EGL(4435): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.08+13
10-21 23:57:28.981: I/Adreno-EGL(4435): Build Date: 03/28/14 Fri
10-21 23:57:28.981: I/Adreno-EGL(4435): Local Branch: 0328_AU200_patches
10-21 23:57:28.981: I/Adreno-EGL(4435): Remote Branch: 
10-21 23:57:28.981: I/Adreno-EGL(4435): Local Patches: 
10-21 23:57:28.981: I/Adreno-EGL(4435): Reconstruct Branch: 
10-21 23:57:29.041: D/OpenGLRenderer(4435): Enabling debug mode 0
10-21 23:57:29.091: D/TextLayoutCache(4435): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-21 23:57:30.941: W/ApplicationPackageManager(4435): getCSCPackageItemText()
10-21 23:57:30.991: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(4435): Parent view is not a TextView
10-21 23:57:31.021: D/AbsListView(4435): Get MotionRecognitionManager
10-21 23:57:31.031: D/AbsListView(4435): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
10-21 23:57:31.031: D/AbsListView(4435): unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-21 23:57:31.041: D/AbsListView(4435): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
10-21 23:57:31.041: D/AbsListView(4435): unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-21 23:57:31.071: D/AbsListView(4435): unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-21 23:57:31.091: D/TextLayoutCache(4435): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-21 23:57:31.091: D/TextLayoutCache(4435): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-21 23:57:31.091: D/TextLayoutCache(4435): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-21 23:57:31.101: D/TextLayoutCache(4435): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-21 23:57:31.101: D/AbsListView(4435): unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-21 23:57:31.111: D/AbsListView(4435): unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-21 23:57:31.121: D/TextLayoutCache(4435): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-21 23:57:31.121: D/TextLayoutCache(4435): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-21 23:57:31.121: D/TextLayoutCache(4435): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-21 23:57:31.121: D/TextLayoutCache(4435): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-21 23:57:31.141: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(4435): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
10-21 23:57:40.671: D/AbsListView(4435): unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-22 00:00:30.881: D/AbsListView(4435): unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-22 00:00:30.991: D/AbsListView(4435): unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-22 00:01:02.021: D/dalvikvm(4435): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
10-22 00:01:28.041: D/AbsListView(4435): unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-22 00:01:28.621: D/AbsListView(4435): onDetachedFromWindow
10-22 00:01:28.621: D/AbsListView(4435): unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-22 00:01:46.421: W/ApplicationPackageManager(6897): getCSCPackageItemText()
10-22 00:01:46.441: I/PersonaManager(6897): getPersonaService() name persona_policy
10-22 00:01:46.501: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(6897): Parent view is not a TextView
10-22 00:01:46.611: D/dalvikvm(6897): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 81K, 37% free 17033K/26708K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
10-22 00:01:46.641: I/dalvikvm-heap(6897): Grow heap (frag case) to 33.307MB for 12582928-byte allocation
10-22 00:01:46.751: D/TextLayoutCache(6897): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-22 00:01:46.781: I/Adreno-EGL(6897): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
10-22 00:01:46.781: I/Adreno-EGL(6897): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.08+13
10-22 00:01:46.781: I/Adreno-EGL(6897): Build Date: 03/28/14 Fri
10-22 00:01:46.781: I/Adreno-EGL(6897): Local Branch: 0328_AU200_patches
10-22 00:01:46.781: I/Adreno-EGL(6897): Remote Branch: 
10-22 00:01:46.781: I/Adreno-EGL(6897): Local Patches: 
10-22 00:01:46.781: I/Adreno-EGL(6897): Reconstruct Branch: 
10-22 00:01:46.821: D/OpenGLRenderer(6897): Enabling debug mode 0
10-22 00:01:46.871: D/TextLayoutCache(6897): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-22 00:01:49.051: W/ApplicationPackageManager(6897): getCSCPackageItemText()
10-22 00:01:49.071: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(6897): Parent view is not a TextView
10-22 00:01:49.101: D/AbsListView(6897): Get MotionRecognitionManager
10-22 00:01:49.121: D/AbsListView(6897): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
10-22 00:01:49.121: D/AbsListView(6897): unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-22 00:01:49.131: D/AbsListView(6897): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
10-22 00:01:49.131: D/AbsListView(6897): unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-22 00:01:49.141: D/AbsListView(6897): unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-22 00:01:49.181: D/TextLayoutCache(6897): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-22 00:01:49.181: D/TextLayoutCache(6897): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-22 00:01:49.191: D/TextLayoutCache(6897): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-22 00:01:49.191: D/TextLayoutCache(6897): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-22 00:01:49.191: D/AbsListView(6897): unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-22 00:01:49.191: D/TextLayoutCache(6897): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-22 00:01:49.191: D/TextLayoutCache(6897): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-22 00:01:49.201: D/TextLayoutCache(6897): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-22 00:01:49.201: D/TextLayoutCache(6897): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-22 00:01:49.211: D/AbsListView(6897): unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-22 00:01:49.221: D/AbsListView(6897): unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-22 00:01:51.121: D/AbsListView(6897): unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-22 00:01:51.121: W/ApplicationPackageManager(6897): getCSCPackageItemText()
10-22 00:01:51.141: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(6897): Parent view is not a TextView
10-22 00:01:51.221: D/my_Email(6897): onCreate method invoked sucessful
10-22 00:01:51.261: D/TextLayoutCache(6897): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-22 00:01:51.261: D/TextLayoutCache(6897): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-22 00:01:51.261: D/TextLayoutCache(6897): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-22 00:01:51.261: D/TextLayoutCache(6897): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-22 00:01:51.271: D/TextLayoutCache(6897): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-22 00:01:51.271: D/TextLayoutCache(6897): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-22 00:01:51.271: D/TextLayoutCache(6897): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-22 00:01:51.301: D/TextLayoutCache(6897): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-22 00:01:51.301: D/TextLayoutCache(6897): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-22 00:01:51.311: D/TextLayoutCache(6897): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-22 00:01:51.311: D/TextLayoutCache(6897): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-22 00:01:51.311: D/TextLayoutCache(6897): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-22 00:01:51.311: D/TextLayoutCache(6897): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-22 00:01:51.311: D/TextLayoutCache(6897): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-22 00:01:51.671: D/AbsListView(6897): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
10-22 00:01:51.671: D/AbsListView(6897): unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-22 00:01:52.581: D/my_Email(6897): onClick method invoked sucessful
10-22 00:01:52.581: D/my_Email(6897): String Array invoked sucessful
10-22 00:01:52.581: D/AndroidRuntime(6897): Shutting down VM
10-22 00:01:52.581: W/dalvikvm(6897): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417d1da0)
10-22 00:01:52.581: E/AndroidRuntime(6897): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-22 00:01:52.581: E/AndroidRuntime(6897): Process: com.example.first, PID: 6897
10-22 00:01:52.581: E/AndroidRuntime(6897): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-22 00:01:52.581: E/AndroidRuntime(6897):     at com.example.first.Email.onClick(Email.java:57)
10-22 00:01:52.581: E/AndroidRuntime(6897):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4630)
10-22 00:01:52.581: E/AndroidRuntime(6897):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19339)
10-22 00:01:52.581: E/AndroidRuntime(6897):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-22 00:01:52.581: E/AndroidRuntime(6897):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-22 00:01:52.581: E/AndroidRuntime(6897):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
10-22 00:01:52.581: E/AndroidRuntime(6897):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
10-22 00:01:52.581: E/AndroidRuntime(6897):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-22 00:01:52.581: E/AndroidRuntime(6897):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-22 00:01:52.581: E/AndroidRuntime(6897):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
10-22 00:01:52.581: E/AndroidRuntime(6897):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
10-22 00:01:52.581: E/AndroidRuntime(6897):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-22 00:01:54.381: I/Process(6897): Sending signal. PID: 6897 SIG: 9
10-22 00:01:54.651: W/ApplicationPackageManager(7555): getCSCPackageItemText()
10-22 00:01:54.651: I/PersonaManager(7555): getPersonaService() name persona_policy
10-22 00:01:54.691: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(7555): Parent view is not a TextView
10-22 00:01:54.721: D/AbsListView(7555): Get MotionRecognitionManager
10-22 00:01:54.751: D/AbsListView(7555): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
10-22 00:01:54.751: D/AbsListView(7555): unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-22 00:01:54.761: D/AbsListView(7555): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
10-22 00:01:54.761: D/AbsListView(7555): unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-22 00:01:54.771: D/AbsListView(7555): unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-22 00:01:54.771: D/TextLayoutCache(7555): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-22 00:01:54.791: I/Adreno-EGL(7555): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
10-22 00:01:54.791: I/Adreno-EGL(7555): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.08+13
10-22 00:01:54.791: I/Adreno-EGL(7555): Build Date: 03/28/14 Fri
10-22 00:01:54.791: I/Adreno-EGL(7555): Local Branch: 0328_AU200_patches
10-22 00:01:54.791: I/Adreno-EGL(7555): Remote Branch: 
10-22 00:01:54.791: I/Adreno-EGL(7555): Local Patches: 
10-22 00:01:54.791: I/Adreno-EGL(7555): Reconstruct Branch: 
10-22 00:01:54.861: D/OpenGLRenderer(7555): Enabling debug mode 0
10-22 00:01:54.871: D/TextLayoutCache(7555): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-22 00:01:54.871: D/TextLayoutCache(7555): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-22 00:01:54.871: D/TextLayoutCache(7555): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-22 00:01:54.871: D/TextLayoutCache(7555): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-22 00:01:54.871: D/AbsListView(7555): unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-22 00:01:54.881: D/TextLayoutCache(7555): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-22 00:01:54.881: D/TextLayoutCache(7555): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-22 00:01:54.881: D/TextLayoutCache(7555): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-22 00:01:54.881: D/TextLayoutCache(7555): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-22 00:01:54.891: D/TextLayoutCache(7555): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-22 00:01:54.921: D/AbsListView(7555): unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-22 00:01:54.941: D/AbsListView(7555): unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-22 00:01:55.011: D/AbsListView(7555): unregisterIRListener() is called
```

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: i dont know how to use  the logcat

Comment: you can save your logcat in a file. Just copy the text stored in that file and add it via an edit to your question. What IDE are you using for development? Android Studio or Eclipse or something else?

Comment: Eclipse I just did sir...

Comment: @SebastianWalla sir can you suggest me any site or something to learn android more easily as i found "developers.android" much difficult

Comment: @Kamil I myself learned developing for android the patchy way. This means you're learning by doing. You say, you want to programm something. And for every problem, which occurs you need to solve it. Googling the errors will often lead, to this site, which is, in my opinion, the best for getting problems solved. Many people before, had similar problems and you just need to learn, how they solved their problem and adapt it to your problem. There are many voices, which say, patchy learning is not the right way, but for me it did work out.

Comment: If you get more used to developing for android, you will also be able to understand the android api much easier. But I can't show you the right way for you. This question is often asked and but reluctant to be seen here, because this is based on opinion and no answer, which works for everybody.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a `NullPointerException` in your `onClick()` method. This is because you never initialized `emailAdd`. You did only declare it, but didn't give it a value.

I think you know, how to assign a value to a variable, but to be for sure, as an example:

```
emailAdd="some value";
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it crashes because of this:

```
name = personName.getText().toString();
```

personName does not refer to anything. So I think this is a typo:

```
personEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
intro = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
personEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
```

So change this to:

```
personEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
intro = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
personName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
```

And try again

Comment: Thank you so much guys i really appreciate your help

Comment: @Kamil Please upvote answers, that helped you and accept the answer, that solved your problem. So other people with a similar problem can see, what helped to solve it.

Comment: I tried but it keep saying that once my total reputation will 15 it will count then only